# How to use msclr\marshal_cppstd in two dependent classes

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I need to use msclr in my code, but I also need to use an other class "ClassOne" that also uses msclr. I get 'class' type redefinition errors and base class undefined errors. I don't know why this is happening.

Both classes are in the same project. Errors appear when I do #using "ClassOne.obj"

How can I avoid this?

**ClassOne.h:**

```
#ifndef _CLASSONE_H
#define _CLASSONE_H

ref class ClassOne
{
public:
    ClassOne();
};
#endif
```

**ClassOne.cpp:**

```
#include "ClassOne.h"
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h> // For msclr::interop::marshal_as

ClassOne::ClassOne()
{
}
```

**ClassTwo.h:**

```
#ifndef _CLASSTWO_H
#define _CLASSTWO_H
#using "ClassOne.obj"

public ref class ClassTwo
{
public:
    ClassOne a;
    ClassTwo();
};
#endif
```

**ClassTwo.cpp:**

```
#include "ClassTwo.h"
#include <msclr/marshal_cppstd.h>

ClassTwo::ClassTwo()
{
    msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::wstring>(L"text");
}
```

**Errors:**

See screenshot: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPfUY.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
#using "ClassOne.obj"
```

I have no idea what this is. I've never seen a using directive on an obj file before; I'm not sure what the purpose is. Frankly, I'm surprised that you're not getting an error on that `#using` line.

If you want to reference `ClassOne` from `ClassTwo`, include the *header file*, just like regular C++.

```
#using "ClassOne.h"
```